# Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Lazy`1[System.Net.Http.IHttpClientFactory]' while attempting to activate service

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, dotnet-httpclient

I am getting the below error while trying to inject Lazy.

It works fine without "Lazy<>"

I have registered it like below in startup.cs.

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHttpClient();
        ..

        ..
   }
```

I am trying to inject it in a controller like below:

```
 private readonly Lazy<IHttpClientFactory> _clientFactory;
    protected IHttpClientFactory ClientFactory => _clientFactory.Value;

    public ValuesController(Lazy<IHttpClientFactory> clientFactory)
    {
         _clientFactory = clientFactory;
    }
```

Here, I am getting an error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Lazy`1[System.Net.Http.IHttpClientFactory]' while attempting to activate 'POC.Core.Controllers.ValuesController'.'
```

Any idea, what could be the issue in lazy initialization?

Comment: Why are you using `Lazy<>`? What do you expect it to do? HttpClientFactory itself is the type meant to create instances of other types. It's essentially a singleton managed by the DI container itself so `Lazy<IHttpClientFactory>` won't have any effect

Comment: The built-in dependency registration does not wrap values in `Lazy<T>` - you'd either have to do it yourself (which adds little benefit and increases complexity), or just not use `Lazy<T>` and resolve the service by itself.

Comment: @MartinCostello: I have done that in the past(maybe with older versions of microsoft.extensions.http). Is it something because of the newer versions of microsoft.extensions.http? I cannot downgrade in my current project to validate that due to lot of dependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't use `Lazy<IHttpClientFactory>`. HttpClientFactory itself is the type that creates and caches instances of HttpClients, or rather, HttpClientHandlers.

It's [a singleton](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/57bfe474518ab5b7cfe6bf7424a79ce3af9d6657/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DependencyInjection/HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L37)managed by the DI container itself so `Lazy<IHttpClientFactory>` wouldn't have any effect, even if you got it to compile.

The source code of [AddHttpClient](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/57bfe474518ab5b7cfe6bf7424a79ce3af9d6657/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DependencyInjection/HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L23) explicitly registers a default HttpClientFactory as a singleton.

```
    public static IServiceCollection AddHttpClient(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        if (services == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
        }

        services.AddLogging();
        services.AddOptions();

        //
        // Core abstractions
        //
        services.TryAddTransient<HttpMessageHandlerBuilder, DefaultHttpMessageHandlerBuilder>();
        services.TryAddSingleton<DefaultHttpClientFactory>();
```

Comment: Got it, Thanks. The only doubt remains in my mind is - I have done that in the past(maybe with older versions of microsoft.extensions.http). Is it something because of the newer versions of microsoft.extensions.http? I cannot downgrade in my current project to validate that due to lot of dependency

Comment: This has nothing to do with `Microsoft.Extensions.Http`. `Lazy` was never required. Perhaps you registered a factory method that returned a `Lazy<>` in the past, but the actual HttpClientFactory was always a singleton.